# Fail to store encrypted credentials for SMB pull server in LCM's meta-configuration (PS 4.0)

Tags: powershell, credentials, powershell-4.0, dsc

I'm new to DSC and I've been trying for days now to have my meta-configuration working with an SMB pull server, to no avail.

Context:

- Target nodes are Win 2012 R2 servers, members of a same domain
- I can only use PS 4.0
- I can't give read access to everyone on SMB share on pull server
- I don't want to have pull mode relying on custom modules to be functional (only base PS 4.0 installation)
- My authoring node is currently my test target node
- I tried to use `New-SelfsignedCertificateEx.ps1` but can't get it to run on my Windows 7
- I'm using a self-signed certificate generated on Windows 10 with requested KUs and EKUs
- My meta-configuration works with an SMB share without credentials (hosted by test target node itself / read access granted to everyone)

I've been searching the web but only found code examples or questions about credentials passed to a DSC resource. I haven't found an example of PS 4.0 code where a live `PSCredential` object (retrieved from `Get-Credential` cmdlet) gets encrypted on-the-fly to a meta-configuration mof.

I've tried to transpose numerous examples (including from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/securemof) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/01/31/want-to-secure-credentials-in-windows-powershell-desired-state-configuration/)), but I'm unable to have my credentials encrypted and still get that well-known message each time:

```ps
ConvertTo-MOFInstance : System.InvalidOperationException error processing property 'Credential' OF TYPE 'LocalConfigurationManager': Converting and 
storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For more information on securing credentials in MOF file, please refer to MSDN blog: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729
At line:190 char:16
+     $aliasId = ConvertTo-MOFInstance $keywordName $canonicalizedValue
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToProcessProperty,ConvertTo-MOFInstance
Errors occurred while processing configuration 'MetaConfigurationForPull'.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\PSDesiredStateConfiguration.psm1:2223 char:5
+     throw $errorRecord
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MetaConfigurationForPull:String) [], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToProcessConfiguration
```

Here's my code:

```ps
# Getting credentials for filer connection (CIFS share for pulling MOF files)
$cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Provide credentials for CIFS share hosting configuration files:'

Configuration MetaConfigurationForPull {
    Param (
        [PSCredential] $Credential
    )

    LocalConfigurationManager {
        ConfigurationID = "f28a102c-71c9-43a1-abbb-a944ec7cb5cd";
        CertificateID = $AllNodes.Thumbprint;
        Credential = $Credential;
        RefreshMode = "PULL";
        RebootNodeIfNeeded = $false;
        DownloadManagerName = "DscFileDownloadManager";
        DownloadManagerCustomData = @{SourcePath = '\\smb_pull_server\smb_share\mofs\batch_server'};
    }
}

$ConfigData= @{ 
    AllNodes = @(     
            @{  
                # The name of the node we are describing
                NodeName = "localhost"

                # The path to the .cer file containing the
                # public key of the Encryption Certificate
                # used to encrypt credentials for this node
                CertificateFile = "D:\node_rdp_cert.cer"

                # The thumbprint of the Encryption Certificate
                # used to decrypt the credentials on target node
                Thumbprint = "d78334010df5dee5de1c7529e9419a4bb841e618"
            };
        );
    }

MetaConfigurationForPull -Credential $cred -ConfigurationData $ConfigData -Output "D:\meta\batch_server"
```

I've also found [that post](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/12453480-issue-with-dscfiledownloadmanager-credentials) which talks about some regression on PS 5.0 and where this guy states he had everything working like a charm on PS 4.0.

**Am I missing something in the code above?**
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Still looking for an answer ...
Is there a known bug in PS 4.0 which prevents LCM from storing access credentials for an SMB pull server ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as this is just a test environment, you can add:

```
PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
```

to your configuration.

Example: [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSDscResources/blob/dev/Tests/Integration/MSFT_UserResource.Integration.Tests.ps1#L35).

Comment: Sure, I can test with that, but my main concern remains how to make this work on production environment with encryption!

Comment: Is there an official bug in PS 4.0 which prevents LCM from storing access credentials for an SMB pull server ?